# How to post form from iFrame to parent

Tags: php, mysql

I am using iFrame `mail-data.php` embedded in `payin.php` page in which I enter user details for mailing.

1. Can I pass data from `payin.php` (original page) page to `mail-data.php` (iFrame) based on id retrieved from database?
2. How can I post data from `mail-data.php` (iFrame) to another page `mail.php` to execute `mail` function? If yes, how can I pass data from ordinary page to an iFrame page?

I tried using form action in iFrame page to `mail.php`, however I got the error which is shown.

```
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /radical/mail-data.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What may be the issue?

Comment: is the page in the iframe from the same domain as the parent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sample shows how you can use the `target` attribute of a form element to send the form request through the iframe:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" name="mail-data" />

<form action="mail-data.php" method="post" target="mail-data">
    <!-- form fields !-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the id value with the help of href to mail-data.php and then retreived the id by using get method ..It worked perfectly fine

thanks